Can the higher order corrections to energy be calculated the same way in degenerate perturbation theory as with non-degenerate perturbation theory?
Consider the system given by,
$$ H|n\rangle = E|n\rangle$$
where:

$H$ is the hamiltonian.
$|n\rangle$ is the eigenstate.
$E$ is the energy of the eigenstate.

Now from non-degenerate perturbation theory, we get the following formula for the higher-order corrections to the energy,
$$ E^{(s)} = \langle n^{(0)}|\delta H|n^{(s-1)}\rangle\tag{1.1.26}$$
where:

$E^{(s)}$ is the $s^{th}$ order correction to the energy.
$|n^{(s-1)}\rangle$ is the $(s-1)^{th}$ order correction to the eigenstate.
$\delta H$ is the perturbation applied to the hamiltonian $H$.

A reference to this formula can be found here, equation number (1.1.26).
Can we use the same equation (with same bra-eigenstate (non-degenerate) but the ket-eigenstate replaced by the degenerate eigenstate) to calculate the higher order corrections to the energies in degenerate perturbation theory with the'correct' eigenstates?
I can find no reason that this equation will not hold for the degenerate case if the correct eigenbasis is used, but my experience in quantum mechanics or linear algebra is only limited.
To be specific, is the following equation (with the mentioned definitions) correct?
$$ E_{k}^{(s)} = \langle p^{(0)}|\delta H|(n;k)^{(s-1)}\rangle$$
where:

$\delta H$ is the perturbation applied to the hamiltonian $H$.
$p$ is an eigenstate in the non-degenerate subspace.
$(n;k)$ is the $k^{th}$ eigenstate among the $n$ degenerate eigenstates.
The degenerate state $|(n;k)^{(s-1)}\rangle$, will have a component in non-degenerate subspace $\widehat{V}$ as well as the degenerate subspace $V_{N}$.
$E_{k}^{(s)}$ is the $s^{th}$ correction to the energy of the $k^{th}$ degenerate state among the $n$ degenerate states.

Note: For the case of s=1, the bra-eigenstate must also be the degenerate eigenstate $(n;k)^{0}$ (instead of the non-degenerate state $p^{0}$).
For the non-degenerate correction to the higher order energy $E_{p}^{(s)}$, we can use the non-degenerate equation to calculate the $s^{th}$ correction to the $p^{th}$ (one of the non-degenerate) state.

the issue with degeneracies is this: the unperturbed eigenstates are no longer unique, and it matters which you choose; for perturbation theory to work, you have to choose linear combinations $|n\rangle$ of the unperturbed eigenstates such that the off-diagonal element $\langle n|\delta H|m\rangle$, $n\neq m$, of the perturbation vanishes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Effects_of_degeneracy and references therein.

Hello Dr. @CarloBeenakker. Yes. My question is, after using the correct eigenstates (the ones that diagonalize the perturbation $\delta H$), can I use the the formula mentioned above to calculate all higher order energy corrections if I know the previous order corrections to the respective eigenstates (which will include the previous order corrections to energy)?

yes, that is correct.

Dr. @CarloBeenakker, the reason I ask this, is because all the references that I looked at only give the general formula (equation 1.1.26) for non-degenerate perturbation theory and not for degenerate perturbation theory. I am really trying to find an answer to the question I asked here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/835889/how-to-calculate-the-full-second-order-correction-to-the-eigenvalues-in-degenera. I would be grateful if you took a look at it. Thank you.

see for example https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/150953/38462
